# Does node_redis (npm redis module) support redis cluster mode or do we have to use ioredis?

Tags: node.js, node-redis, amazon-elasticache, redis-cluster, ioredis

We are using node_redis (npm redis module) on node js to connect with AWS elasticache. We are now planning to use cluster mode and seeing failures when using node_redis. It is not handling MOVE commands.

Do we have to do anything specific for node_redis to work with cluster mode? or is that not supported and we have to use ioredis?

Answer (score 3):

It's provided through a separate module called [redis-clustr](https://github.com/gosquared/redis-clustr) endorsed by redis. But it's usage is not that high. Here is the official word from redis labs [Source](https://redislabs.com/lp/node-js-redis/),

> Node.js has two primary clients available node_redis and ioredis. Both are available through npm. Both clients have pros and cons, but we generally suggest node_redis, as it has wide support for Redis modules, it is easily extensible and widely used. Ioredis has better integrated support for the Redis Enterprise Cluster API, but this is only relevant if your specifically using the Cluster API topology instead of the more common Proxy topology. Node_redis’ support for the Cluster API is provided by an additional shim, redis-clustr. Node_redis has built-in support for Redis Enterprise features such as Active Active geo distribution, allowing you to have one database that spans multiple clusters. Node_redis also supports Redis-on-Flash which enables extending your database into Flash SSD storage for warm values and DRAM for hot values.

Comment: Thanks Kalana for the response. As you mentioned the use of redis-clustr seems very low so wondering what other people do? Do they use ioRedis? or People don't use AWS elasticache with cluster mode enabled?

Comment: They, myself included use ioredis. Once had to convert from entirely to ioredis due to clustering some time back. But I haven't used aws elasticache so cannot really comment on it.

Comment: Did anyone succeed to use ioredis or any other client for AWS elasticache redis (cluster mode enabled)?

Comment: Even we are looking to migrate to AWS elasticache redis (cluster mode enabled). We are able to use it with ioredis but on load testing the concurrent connections are increasing and getting the error - https://github.com/luin/ioredis/issues/711
So we have not gone to production yet. Still looking for solution. Would appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It supports cluster mode using the function `createCluster`. In our app, we support both by having 2 configurations - one for the Redis URL and the other for the mode -`standalone` or `cluster`. Based on the mode, we use either createCluster or createClient.

```
  if (config.redis.mode === 'cluster') {
    connection = createCluster({ rootNodes: [{ url: config.redis.url }] });
  } else {
    connection = createClient({ url: config.redis.url });
  }
  await connection.connect();
```

Comment: Official reference doc: https://github.com/redis/node-redis/blob/c64ce74383018266015e1fff6394261dad243dd1/docs/clustering.md